# Examples of self-normalizing subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, examples-counterexamples

I know that when $G$ is a $p$-group every proper subgroup is a proper subgroup of its normalizer. I was hoping to get some simple and not-so-simple examples of a subgroup that equals its normalizer. Thanks!

Comment: For example every maximal non-normal subgroup is equal to its normalizer.

Comment: Can I get a few concrete examples?

Comment: $\langle (1\ \ 2)\rangle$ as a subgroup of $S_3$ is a standard example. (it is non-normal and has a prime index)

Comment: Can anyone find a (finite or infinite) non-abelian simple group all of whose nontrivial subgroups are also simple? In such a group, any nontrivial subgroup would not only be simple but also self-normalizing.

Comment: Note that a finite group where every subgroup is strictly contained in its normalizer is necessarily nilpotent (in fact, the converse is true as well). So we are looking for non-nilpotent groups

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang The only finite simple groups with that property are the groups of prime order. This is because such a group would need to have Sylow $p$-subgroups isomorphic to $C_p$ for every prime $p$ dividing the order and such a group is supersoluble (and in particular not non-abelian simple).

Comment: @EpsilonDelta I knew that the converse was true, but I didn't know that that was a characterizing property of nilpotent groups. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a group is nilpotent, you won't be able to find such a subgroup unless you take the whole group. Otherwise, any non-normal maximal subgroup is self-normalising. (Note that a group is nilpotent if and only if every maximal subgroup is normal.)

Carter subgroups are another interesting source of examples of self-normalising subgroups. A subgroup $C$ is called a Carter subgroup if it is nilpotent and self-normalising. As such it is a maximal nilpotent subgroup, but not every maximal nilpotent subgroup is a Carter subgroup. Note that, in general, not every group has a Carter subgroup. For example, $A_5$ has no Carter subgroups.

The interesting theorem proved by Carter is this:

> In a soluble group, there exist Carter subgroups and all Carter
>   subgroups are conjugate.